# por que no me carga un usuario nuevo

Tags: php

hola quien me puede colaborar es que me aparece registro ingresado correctamente pero no me lo guarda en mi crud ni en la base de datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. El código se comparte como texto, por favor ve a [edit] y reemplaza la imagen por el código que nos quieres compartir. Revisa también los logs de PHP y busca errores relacionados; si los hay, añádelos a la pregunta también (como texto).

Comment: si lees bien jamas estas haciendo el insert, solo estas haciendo un select, la variable sentencia las estas reescribiendo 3 veces y al final ejecutas un select
hace siempre un copy paste de tu codigo, es mas facil ayudar

Comment: entonces como puedo solucionar el error es que e intentado de muchas formas y no me da :(

Comment: que error te sale?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: bro es que estoy intentando agregar en mi crud un nuevo usuario y no me lo guarda

Comment: <?php
     NuevoUsuario($_POST['NOMBRE'], $_POST['DESCRIPCION'], $_POST['status']);

 function NuevoUsuario($nombress, $descripcion, $status)
 {
  include '../php/conexion.php';
  $sentencia="INSERT INTO documento_prenomina (nombress, descripcion, status) VALUES ('".$nombress."', '".$descripcion."', '".$status."')";
  $conexion->query($sentencia) or die ("Error al crear usuario: ".mysqli_error($conexion));



  echo '<script>';
   echo 'alert("Usuario creado exitosamente!!");';
   echo 'window.location.href="../nav/pag_user.php";';
  echo '</script>';

 }
?>

Comment: le undo al boton agregar dice usuario creado exitosamente y cuando veo en mi crud no me carga los datos del campo nombress y no se por que :(

Comment: Warning: Undefined array key "NOMBRE" in C:\xampp\htdocs\Logins\nav\documento_prenomina2.php on line 2

Warning: Undefined array key "DESCRIPCION" in C:\xampp\htdocs\Logins\nav\documento_prenomina2.php on line 2

Warning: Undefined array key "status" in C:\xampp\htdocs\Logins\nav\documento_prenomina2.php on line 2
Error al crear usuario: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''documento_prenomina' ('nombress', 'descripcion', 'status') VALUES ('', '', '')' at line 1 me sale este error

Comment: Podrías poner la información extra en la pregunta por favor? Como habrás notado, en los comentarios no se ven bien los mensajes de error. Si no sabes donde está el botón editar, mencioname con @dantes. y veré tu comentario.

Comment: PODEMOS HABLAR POR GMAIL jlopezramirez545@gmail.com

Comment: HE INTENTADO DE TANTAS MANERAS Y NO ME QUIERE GUARDAR EL NUEVO USUARIO NO SE POR QUE :(